# Python webpage scraping can't find form from this page

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize

I want to cycle thru the dates at the bottom of the page using what looks like a form. But it is returning a blank. Here is my code.

```
import mechanize

URL='http://www.airchina.com.cn/www/jsp/airlines_operating_data/exlshow_en.jsp'

br = mechanize.Browser()
r=br.open(URL)

for form in br.forms(): #finding the name of the form
    print form.name
    print form
```

Why is this not returning any forms? it is not a form? if not, how do I control the `year` and `month` at the bottom to cycle thru the pages?

Can someone provide some sample code on how to do it?

Comment: Can't see any form on page. In any case I suspect your forms process through javascript templates or ajax calls. Mechanize can parse only direct html response and doesn't handle forms created with time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to access that page what you are actually doing  is being directed to an error page.  Paste that url in a browser and you get a page with:

```
Not comply with the conditions of the inquiry data
```

and no forms at all

You need to access the page in a different way.  I would suggest stepping throught the url directory until you find the right path.

Comment: yeah, you are right, I had the wrong URL. It somehow diverted to another URL.